# lspci приводит к этому "pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci"

Tags: proxmox, openvz, ubuntu

Виртуальное окружение ProxMox 2.1-14, OpenVZ контейнер, гостевая система Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. При попытке из гостевой вызвать lspci получается такое:

```
\# lspcipcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pcilspci: Cannot find any working access method.
```

Как победить?

Comment: Что говорит cat /etc/mtab | grep proc

Comment: \# cat /etc/mtab | grep procproc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0

Comment: А тут что cat /proc/bus/pci/devices

Comment: \# cat /proc/bus/pci/devicescat: /proc/bus/pci/devices: No such file or directoryболее того:\# ls -l /proc/busls: cannot access /proc/bus: No such file or directory

Comment: Ну вот собственно и все, значит что в виртуалке девайсы не доступны.

Comment: и.. у меня был вопрос: "как победить?" ))

Comment: Пробрасывать их в контейнер с хоста?! --pci_add

Comment: Ааааа!! Крутяк!! Пятак! Оно самое! Сделай ответом, плюсану! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробрасывать их в контейнер с хоста?! --pci_add

Comment: да, всё именно так. пробросил в виртуалку лишнюю сетевуху и ошибка пропала.спасибо ))